# Haskell define a datatype

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell an come across something like the following:

```
data ABC :: * where
 Empty :: ABC
 Single :: Char -> ABC
```

what does the above mean? And what does it mean when we say "write a ABC representing something"?

Comment: ABC is a datatype. This particular datatype is written using the GADT (Generalized algebraic datatype) syntax - this is sort of unusual, and normally you would write it as `data ABC = Empty | Single Char`. Hopefully the meaning of this latter form is clearer - if not, you should take a look at a introductory [Haskell tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: @user2407038 thx a lot for your reply.I know the basic syntax of Haskell, but I just don't understand what does it mean by "write a ABC representing something"?

Comment: The interpretation of a datatype - what a datatype "represents" - is not baked into the language, but rather it comes from the model. For example, a linked list can *represent* a stack. But you wouldn't refer to a list as a stack unless you were using it as one. `ABC` is isomorphic to `Maybe Char` but that is about all that can be said without knowing anything about the problem being modeled. In general, when you say "write a datatype representing ...", you mean translate your model into concrete Haskell (or any other language) syntax.

Comment: Can you point me to some resources or direction...I am so stuck...dont even know where to start when all this data, type things appear...

Comment: @user2407038, one could argue that a strict purely functional list (i.e., `data List a = Nil | Cons a !(List a)`) *is* a stack, because it supports precisely the stack operations and nothing more.

Comment: @xcoder, do you have any prior programming experience?

Comment: Yes, I know Java. And I can actually write functions in Haskell. But now my problem is like, I don;t know what I should achieve...

Comment: @xcoder, okay, so pretend `ABC` is a Java class, and find a way to represent something using it?

Comment: um...that might be the problem I am having..."find a way to represent something using it", I don't quite get the question...I mean, isn;t ABC already a representation of something? It's an object.

Comment: Or do you mean, a parent class called Shape. And a child class called Circle that extends Shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is identical to the standard datatype syntax in Haskell. In particular, the type `ABC` is the same as

```
data ABC = Empty | Single Char
```

The syntax including the `where` clause is called "GADT syntax" and it offers some extra expressiveness by allowing clear syntax for "existential types" and "type equalities". Both of these are rather advanced topics, though. Stick with basic types until you get your water legs.